# Field.set returns empty string in Java

Tags: java, string, exception

The column name below is of the type double.

```
Class c = this.getClass();
Field t = c.getDeclaredField(columnName);
t.setDouble(this,Double.parseDouble(""));
```

the last line throws an exception of "empty String"

I need to insert empty string in t and the column in which I am trying to insert the empty string is of type Double. Can anyone help and provide an alternative?

Comment: How do you imagine putting an empty ``String`` into a ``Double`` field is supposed to work?

Comment: How can i then display nothing in that field. Setting null throws the exception that double cant be set to null

Comment: You can't?  A `double` needs to have a value.  uninitialized doubles are set to the default value of `0.0`.  If you have control over `columnName`, you can make it a `Double` instead of `double` (object instead of primative), which is allowed to be null.

Comment: For the above, you'll also need to use the `set()` method instead of `setDouble()`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set empty values or null on a primitive. If you **absolutely** need to set it to null, then change the field's data type to java.lang.Double, then call `t.set(this, null)`

The failure is caused by your attempt to parse "" as a double, not by the value being set.

Comment: It says cannot set double field to null value

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you want to set null, then make the field's type ``java.lang.Double`` (the wrapper type), not ``double``

Answer (score 0):

parseDouble returns a primitive double containing the value of the string:

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

The reasons of exceptions :

> Throws:
>
> NullPointerException - if the string is null
>
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.

The Javadoc is your friend : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

For your problem, if you take time to read the javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#setDouble(java.lang.Object,%20double)

You can see for this method (setDouble)

> Throws :
>
> NullPointerException - if the specified object is null and the field is an instance field.

so you can use it :

```
Double d = Double.valueOf("0.0");
t.set(this,d);
```

Comment: He wants to set the field to ``null``, not to ``0``. That's not possible with primitives.

Answer (score 0):

An empty `String` is the wrong way to go here. You want to set the value to `null`, which basically means "no value".

Use this:

```
Class c = this.getClass();
Field t = c.getDeclaredField(columnName);
t.set(this, null);
```

Please note that this will only work if the type of your field is `Double`, not `double`.

`double` is a primitive type and as such, there is no real way of representing "no value". `Double` objects are not primitives, but object. As such, they can be set to `null`, which is what you want.